# Controller URL does not work

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, controllers

I have the problem that i always get the error 404 not found, if I want to get the url of my controller. This is my filestructure:
[image]

And this is the URL I am trying to get loaded: http://localhost/shoppingcart/index/index
(edit) also tried:
http://localhost/post/index/index

If this URL does not work, which URL should work for my controller?

My base URL is localhost

Whis is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
class Post extends Action
{
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
       Context $context,
         JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
       FormKey $formKey,
       Cart $cart,
       Product $product) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
               $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
         $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
       $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
       try {
               $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId,
                    'qty'   => 1
            );
              $product = $this->product->load($productId);
              $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
              $this->cart->save();
                $result->setData(['message' => __("Product is added in cart")]);
            return $result;
       } catch(\Exception $e) {
               $result->setData(['error' => __($e->getMessage())]);
               return $result;
         }
 }
}
```

This is my routes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <!--define id for frontend route is “standard”-->
   <router id="standard">
       <!--Route name-->
       <route id="post" frontName="post">
           <!--Module name-->
           <module name="MassiveArt_ShoppingCart" />
       </route>
   </router>
</config>
```

Comment: So what is the right URL, if the URL I am trying to get does not work?

Comment: The URL should follow: front_name/controller/action. In your case it will be post/index/index.

Comment: Tried this URL, but did not work as well

Comment: Did you run setup upgrade and redepoy i know it sounds like a simple answer but i had the same issue and this resolved it for me

Comment: I acctually did, but will try it again and run this commands again

Comment: Try to delete your current routes.xml file then recreate the file and try. Sometimes it happens.

Comment: felix, please try to chnage the controller class name to Index and try again with the URL which i provided you.

Comment: that was it @FlyingFinner thank you very much

Comment: if you make it as answer i can mark it as right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller URL follows: front_name/controller/action. So in your case the correct URL will be post/index/index.

Also, you need to change either the controller class name to Index or change the controller file name to Post.php.

Answer (score 2):

Please try by `post/index/post`.

Controller is called by `route_frontname/controller_folder/action_file`.

Your controller file have class name `Post`. Please make sure you have saved it by `Post.php`.